# Using "void" in C

Tags: c

I'm confused about why we need to pass `void` into C functions:

```
int f(void) { return 0; }
```

versus

```
int f() { return 0; }
```

What is the proper thing to do and why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C, `int f()` is an old-style declaration.  It says that `f` expects a fixed but unspecified number and type(s) of arguments.  For example, given `int f() { return 0; }`, the compiler won't complain about `f(42)`, or `f("hello, world")` (though the behavior of such a call is undefined).

`int f(void)` explicitly says that `f` takes no arguments.

(C++ has different rules; Stroustrup wasn't as concerned about backward compatibility with old C code.)

Answer (score 5):

It's a vestige of C.

`f(void)` takes no arguments, so `f(1)` is invalid.

`f()` means that the parameters are unspecified, so `f(1)` is valid here.

Comment: It's "valid" in the sense that the compiler needn't complain about it.  But if the *definition* of `f` doesn't specify any parameters, then the behavior of `f(1)` is undefined.  Without a prototype, it's entirely up to the programmer to get the number and type(s) of the arguments correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `void` in this case just means "there are no parameters." I'm not sure whether your second  case will compile, but either way I'd prefer the first case just to be as clear as possible. Of course, when calling `f`, you just use the empty parentheses:

```
int x = f();
```

Comment: Yes, the second case will compile.  It's a function definition (which includes a function declaration) with no prototype.  It's supported for compatibility with pre-ANSI C.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm glad to learn that from Keith Thompson and not from Ken Thompson. ;-)