# What does void* mean and how to use it?

Tags: c

Today when I was reading others' code, I saw something like `void *func(void* i);`, what does this `void*` mean here for the function name and for the variable type, respectively?

In addition, when do we need to use this kind of pointer and how to use it?

Comment: What C book are you using ? You're asking for the better part of an entire chapter.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming

Comment: Its answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c
and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324860/using-void-in-c

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=void*+%5Bc%5D](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=void*+%5Bc%5D) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590314/what-are-the-reasons-for-casting-a-void-pointer

Comment: Take a cue from `malloc` and `calloc`. The man page goes on to say: "...return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in data type."

Answer (score 241, accepted):

A pointer to `void` is a "generic" pointer type.  A `void *` can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast.  You cannot dereference a `void *` or do pointer arithmetic with it; you must convert it to a pointer to a complete data type first.

`void *` is often used in places where you need to be able to work with different pointer types in the same code.  One commonly cited example is the library function `qsort`:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

`base` is the address of an array, `nmemb` is the number of elements in the array, `size` is the size of each element, and `compar` is a pointer to a function that compares two elements of the array.  It gets called like so:

```
int iArr[10];
double dArr[30];
long lArr[50];
...
qsort(iArr, sizeof iArr/sizeof iArr[0], sizeof iArr[0], compareInt);
qsort(dArr, sizeof dArr/sizeof dArr[0], sizeof dArr[0], compareDouble);
qsort(lArr, sizeof lArr/sizeof lArr[0], sizeof lArr[0], compareLong);
```

The array expressions `iArr`, `dArr`, and `lArr` are implicitly converted from array types to pointer types in the function call, and each is implicitly converted from "pointer to `int`/`double`/`long`" to "pointer to `void`".

The comparison functions would look something like:

```
int compareInt(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
  const int *x = lhs;  // convert void * to int * by assignment
  const int *y = rhs;

  if (*x > *y) return 1;
  if (*x == *y) return 0;
  return -1;
}
```

By accepting `void *`, `qsort` can work with arrays of any type.

The disadvantage of using `void *` is that you throw type safety out the window and into oncoming traffic.  There's nothing to protect you from using the wrong comparison routine:

```
qsort(dArr, sizeof dArr/sizeof dArr[0], sizeof dArr[0], compareInt);
```

`compareInt` is expecting its arguments to be pointing to `int`s, but is actually working with `double`s.  There's no way to catch this problem at compile time; you'll just wind up with a missorted array.

Comment: It's actually not guaranteed that a `void*` can be cast to a function pointer. But for data pointers what you said holds.

Comment: Before void pointers were available "char *" was used instead. But void is better as it cannot actually be used to alter anything directly.

Comment: Similar like generics in Java?

Comment: @GauravKhare: Not...really.  Java generics, like C++ templates, are a language feature designed to support true type polymorphism.  Void pointers are a *hack* to kind-of-sort-of fake type polymorphism.

Answer (score 29):

Using a void * means that the function can take a pointer that doesn't need to be a specific type.
For example, in socket functions, you have

```
send(void * pData, int nLength)
```

this means you can call it in many ways, for example

```
char * data = "blah";
send(data, strlen(data));

POINT p;
p.x = 1;
p.y = 2;
send(&p, sizeof(POINT));
```

Comment: So that's pretty much like generics in other languages, but with no type checking, right?

Comment: I suppose it would be similar, however since there is no type checking, making a mistake can cause very strange results or cause the program to outright crash.

Answer (score 23):

C is remarkable in this regard. One can say `void` is nothingness `void*` is everything (can be everything).

It's just this tiny `*` which makes the difference.

Rene has pointed it out. A `void *` is a Pointer to some location. What there is how to "interpret" is left to the user.

It's the only way to have opaque types in C. Very prominent examples can be found e.g in glib or general data structure libraries. It's treated very detailed in "C Interfaces and implementations".

I suggest you read the complete chapter and try to understand the concept of a pointer to  "get it".

Answer (score 9):

```
void*
```

is a 'pointer to memory with no assumptions what type is there stored'.
You can use, for example, if you want to pass an argument to function and this argument can be of several types and in function you will handle each type.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at this article about pointers http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ and read the chapter : **void pointers**.

This also works for C language.

> The void type of pointer is a special type of pointer. In C++, void
>   represents the absence of type, so void pointers are pointers that
>   point to a value that has no type (and thus also an undetermined
>   length and undetermined dereference properties).
>
> This allows void pointers to point to any data type, from an integer
>   value or a float to a string of characters. But in exchange they have
>   a great limitation: the data pointed by them cannot be directly
>   dereferenced (which is logical, since we have no type to dereference
>   to), and for that reason we will always have to cast the address in
>   the void pointer to some other pointer type that points to a concrete
>   data type before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 3):

A void pointer is known as generic pointer. I would like to explain with a sample pthread scenario.

The thread function will have the prototype as

```
void *(*start_routine)(void*)
```

The pthread API designers considered the argument and return values of thread function. If those thing are made generic, we can type cast to void* while sending as argument. similarly the return value can be retrieved from void*(But i never used return values from thread function).

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;

   // ***Arg sent in main is retrieved   ***
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      //*** t will be type cast to void* and send as argument.
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);   
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }    
   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Why call `pthread_exit(NULL);` instead of `return 0;` at the end of main?

Comment: @Seabass77 Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559463/is-it-ok-to-call-pthread-exit-from-main

Answer (score 2):

C11 standard (n1570) §6.2.2.3 al1 p55 says :

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to
>   void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original
>   pointer.

You can use this generic pointer to store a pointer to any object type, but you can't use usual arithmetic operations with it and you can't deference it.

Answer (score 1):

a `void*` is a pointer, but the type of what it points to is unspecified. When you pass a void pointer to a function you will need to know what its type was in order to cast it back to that correct type later in the function to use it. You will see examples in `pthreads` that use functions with exactly the prototype in your example that are used as the thread function. You can then use the `void*` argument as a pointer to a generic datatype of your choosing and then cast it back to that type to use within your thread function. You need to be careful when using void pointers though as unless you case back to a pointer of its true type you can end up with all sorts of problems.

Answer (score -1):

The function takes a pointer to an arbitrary type and returns one such.

Answer (score -4):

it means pointer you can use this link to get more info about pointer
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html