# About the parameter of function pthread_create?

Tags: pthreads

We know that we call pthread like this:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, 
                    void *(*start_routine) (void *), void* arg);
```

Hi guys, i want to know why the return type of third parameter is `void*`? why not `void`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no way for a start function to know what kind of data a developer wants to return from the function they use a `void*` that can point to any type. It is up to the developer of the start function to then cast the `void*` to appropriate type he actually returned before using whatever the `void*` points to. So now the start function can return a pointer that may in actually point to anything. If the start function is declared to return `void`, it means this function returns nothing, then what if the developer wants the start function to return a int, a struct? For example:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <pthread.h>

struct test {
    char str[32];
    int x;
};

void *func(void*) {
    struct test *eg = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    strcpy(eg->str,"hello world");
    eg->x = 42;
    pthread_exit(eg);
}


int main (void) {
    pthread_t id;
    struct test *resp;

    pthread_create(&id, NULL, func, NULL);
    pthread_join(id,(void**)&resp);

    printf("%s %d\n",resp->str,resp->x);

    free(resp);

    return 0;
}
```

More details on this post: [What does void* mean and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: I know you meaning, but i want to know the return type, not the input parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but the developer how to receive the return value?

Comment: by calling `pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval)`, the second parameter is for this.

Comment: Here is a demo live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f6fee4d834b2457).