# What is the difference between these two C function calls?

Tags: c, linux

I am calling the following library function in two ways:

```
unsigned int
LsSendToQ(unsigned int p4Node, const char queueName[4], lsMsg *pMsg,
          unsigned int prio) {

}
```

The first way :

```
LsSendToQ((unsigned int)0, (const char *)Q_NAME, (lsMsg *)(void *)pMsg, 0)
```

and the second way :

```
LsSendToQ((unsigned int)0, (const char *)Q_NAME, (lsMsg *)pMsg, 0)
```

Both calls compile fine, but which one is the right way ? And why is `(void *)` used in the first call, which looks like a function pointer to me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: How is `Q_NAME` defined? how is `pMsg` defined?  The first cast is useless, `(lsMsg *)(void *)pMsg` is redundant, but might be needed to silence a compiler warning.

Comment: You should avoid redundant casts; try `LsSendToQ(0, Q_NAME, pMsg, prio);`  .  The cast of `pMsg` may be required but we can't tell just based on what you posted.

Comment: As an aside, while the first one is just noise in C I can imagine that it makes a difference in certain inheritance situations in C++, with multiple inheritance. (The cast from and to `void*` would always be a reinterpret_cast while a direct cast may be translated to a static_cast to the address of a sub object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to `void` is a "generic" pointer type. A `void *` can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast. You cannot dereference a `void *` or do pointer arithmetic with it; you must convert it to a pointer to an complete data type first. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629682/694733).

So the parameter `pMsg`is not directly compitable to lsMsg * then the 2nd calling is a possible way to use this in the function calling[ I didn't tested it].

By the way, as long as type of `pMsg` is `lsMsg *` the 1st one is enough.

Edit:

The 2nd one is enough as it covers the 1st one.

Comment: Do not copy content from other answers without giving source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11629682/694733

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hm. "A `void *` can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast.": Wouldn't that imply that the OP could omit the final cast to `lsMsg *`  in `(lsMsg *)(void *)pMsg` (because parameter passing is a form of initialization)? "You cannot dereference a `void *`": Unrelated to the OP's question. "So the parameter pMsg is not directly compitable to `lsMsg *` then the 2nd calling is a possible way to use this in the function calling": true, but the first one as well. So what? "By the way, as long as type of `pMsg` is `lsMsg *` the 1st one is enough." Of course; *no cast* suffices.

Answer (score 3):

The second version is the correct one.

The first call looks like an attempt to dodge incompatible type warnings. If `pMsg` is not compatible with `lsMsg *` you could kill the compiler warning by casting to `void*` in between.

You shouldn't do this though, because it almost certainly hides a bug in your program! Either the two pointer types are completely incompatible, in which case the program may instantly crash & burn upon accessing the pointer. Or they are in theory compatible, but the compiler implements type aliasing and the `(void*)` cast would then hide a violation of the "strict aliasing rule". In either case you have undefined behavior and a severe bug.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for the first way of converting the pointer type twice. Just use the second way is enough.

Comment: I would guess it is a way to quiet a compiler warning about a potentially unsafe casting.