# What is meant by void *p = &i ?

Tags: c, pointers

In below code, how can void pointer p store address of i? What is the   meaning of "*(float *)p" inside printf() ?

```
#include
void main()
{
  int i = 10;
  void *p = &i;
  printf("%f\n", *(float *)p);
}
```

Comment: [Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will tell you what you need to know. As for storing addresses, that's kind of what pointers do.

Comment: "how can void pointer p store address of i" - why do you think `p` can't store the address of `i`?

Comment: Also note that `*(float *)p` is illegal, and  results in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Well if *(float *)p is illegal, I should have got any error or warning in my Code::Blocks. But I didn't get any error. the output of above code is 0.000000.

Comment: @AnjaniKumar Not illegal, it's undefined. It breaks strict aliasing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does void\* mean and how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: @babon because it is declared as void ? I am doubtful.

Comment: @GillBates but it show 0 errors 0 warnings. Should have shown as undefined or some error at least?

Comment: It's not the compiler's job to tell you your code is undefined. Some compilers have extra flags for this but usually this is done with a code analysis tool.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how its output is 0.000000?

Comment: @GillBates thank you for the info. And, Is it undefined because pointer stores address and address is never float but always int ? I am trying my understanding here.

Answer (score 5):

A `void*` can store any address. It's a "generalized pointer" basically. You can cast back the `void*` to the type you saved into it to get a useful type out of it and do things with it like pointer arithmetic or dereferencing the pointer. The pointer itself doesn't know anything about what type it stores and thus you have to tell it what type it's pointing to so. It's lack of type makes it dangerous since it's the programmer's job to remember what type the pointer points to.

In your case, you make `p` point to the address of `i` which is an `int` and then you try to print out the pointee of `p` as a `float` while you didn't assign it to the address of a `float` in the first place. This is undefined behaviour and a good example of the dangers of a `void*` in inexperienced hands.

Answer (score 1):

In C void* can point to any type of memory location. You can assign void* to a variable of type int*, double*, char*.., etc. Generally void* is used to pass parameters to the function who type is not know at the time of defining.

But You can have any variable of type void. So at the time of dereferencing you have to cast a void* to some pointer type but not void*.

so by  `*(float *)p` (which is undefined) you are casting p(which is void* type) to float* type, then you are dereferencing it to double(But memory is actually int). So that it expects float type variable at the memory it is pointing to.

Comment: Any answer to this question needs to mention that the code invokes undefined behavior. Otherwise the answer is misleading people into thinking that the code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> how can void pointer `p` store address of `i`?

A void pointer can point to any data pointer. See [C11 draft, 6.3.2.3.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3) So,

```
void *p = &i;
```

simply makes `p` point to the address of object `i`.
You can later safely convert it back to an `int*`. For example,

```
int i = 10;
void *p = &i;
int *j = p; /* j now point to &i */
```

or you can directly cast `p` and use it:

```
printf("%d\n", *((int*) p));
```

This is all fine.

> What is the meaning of "*(float *)p" inside printf() ?

It's an attempt to reinterpret an `int` object as a `float` object which isn't allowed. In this statement:

```
printf("%f\n", *(float *)p);
```

You are casting `p`, a `void*`, to a `float*` which may be [*undefined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the object `p` points to is an `int` and you are attempting to 
reinterpret it as if it's a `float` object. From [C11 draft, 6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a
>   pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed
>   byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the
>   size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the
>   object.

This also violates [C11 draft, 6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) as `int*` and `float*` are distinct types and are not compatible with each other.

Comment: The quote only hold true if you never dereference this "different object type" pointer.

Comment: @GillBates No, the pointer must also be correctly aligned. If it isn't the mere assignment causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 I know, I was talking about the case where that was true. Even then, it's still UB trying to deref it.

Comment: @GillBates Then you should have mentioned that. And sometimes you can dereference the pointer even with a different type.

Comment: This isn't the whole truth though. The code violates strict aliasing since the pointers point to non-compatible objects of different _effective type_. See C11 6.5.