# Casting Void functions in C

Tags: c, casting, void

Why do so many C functions have Void return types but do not return nothing, for example I was looking at the man page for malloc and it return type is Void, but it also says returns an adress to where it has size_t bytes allocated.

```
void * malloc(size_t  n)

The malloc() functions allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
```

How does casting work in these cases?

Also what does it mean to have type void in a parameter?

The free function has type void.

```
void free(void *ptr)
```

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: don't confuse `void *` and `void`, one mean pointer to something, other mean nothing. Now you asking the question, I'm like... yes in fact it's very misleading !

Comment: "How does casting work in these cases?" => [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` does not return `void` but `void *`. this is a "magic" type in C, because it can be converted into other types of pointer. For function like `malloc()`, only the caller knows what types he will use, so `malloc()` doesn't have to also cannot define the return type. As an alternative, it returns the type of `void *`.

Same reason for the function `free()` which has `*void *ptr` as its parameter.