# Returning a void pointer as a function parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, void

I have a function which returns an array `Data`. The type of the array is either `int` or `float`. I would like to use `void` pointers. If `outputType` is 0 the `Data` would a pointer to an integer array, if not it will point to a float array.

Is it possible to perform this in C?

```
void getData(void *Data , uint8_t outputType)
{
    ...

    int16_t acc[3]={0,0,0}; 

    ...

    acc[0] = (int16_t) ((data[1]*256+data[0]));
    acc[1] = (int16_t) ((data[3]*256+data[2]));
    acc[2] = (int16_t) ((data[5]*256+data[4]));

    Data = acc;

}
```

In the main code:

```
int16_t output[3];
getData(output, 0);
```

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: You need one more level of indirection

Comment: You certainly cannot return the address of a local array. That data is going to be invalid the moment your function returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
void getData(void *Data , uint8_t outputType) {
    if (outputType == 0) {
        int16_t* data = Data;
        /* fill int16_t data here - eg. : */
        data[0] = 42;
    }
    else {
        float* data = Data;
        /* fill float data here - eg. : */
        data[0] = 42.0f;
    }
}
```

All assuming you call it either as :

```
int16_t output[3];
getData(output, 0);
```

or :

```
float output[3];
getData(output, 1);
```

Take special care not to exceed the bounds of the array.

**Explanation**

Any pointer to an object type can be converted to a [`void*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void) and back again to the original type, and the resulting pointer will compare equal to the original pointer.

This can be used (as in this case) to implement generic functions that can work on any pointer type (ref. eg. [What does void* mean and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it)).

There is a caveat though : a `void*` can't be dereferenced (nor can pointer arithmetic be performed on it), so it has to be converted back to the original pointer type before dereferencing. The `outputType` parameter says exactly what that original pointer type was, so the function can perform the proper conversion.

After that, the function can work on the converted pointer as if it were the original pointer. If the original pointer points to an array, then the converted pointer can also be used to access all items of that array.

Comment: The code worked properly! But, would you please describe the mechanism of it?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible to do what you want, but not quite the way you are trying to do it. If you want to pre-allocate the buffer as you are doing, that's fine, and you only need to pass in the pointer itself. Then your problems begin.

First of all, three `int16_t` are not going to be enough to hold the same number of `float` elements (which are usually 4 bytes each). You need to make sure the buffer you pass in is big enough to hold the output.

Secondly, the assignment `Data = acc;` just copies the value of the pointer, not the data that it contains. To do that, you would have to use `memcpy(Data, acc, 3 * sizeof(uint16_t));`, `memmove(Data, acc, 3 * sizeof(uint16_t));`, or something similar. More simply, you could stash the values in the `Data` buffer directly instead of messing with `acc` in the first place.