# Printing variable-type struct elements

Tags: c, pointers, void

I have created a struct to store variable-type elements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum TYPES {TYPE_STRING, TYPE_NUMBER};
struct Value {
    void * value;
    int type; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    // add element one
    struct Value val1;
    val1.value = "Hello";
    val1.type = TYPE_STRING;
    printf("Struct1: {value: %s | type: %d}\n", (char *) val1.value, val1.type);

    // can also initialize it like this
    struct Value val2 = {.value = "goodbye", .type = TYPE_STRING};
    printf("Struct2: {value: %s | type: %d}\n", (char *) val2.value, val2.type);

    // how to initialize a number though?
    int number = 2;
    struct Value val3 = {.value = &number, .type = TYPE_NUMBER};
    printf("Struct2: {value: %d | type: %d}\n", (int) val3.value, val3.type);

}
```

Yet for some reason value3 doesn't print properly.

> main.c:26:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
>   Struct1: {value: Hello | type: 0}
>   Struct2: {value: goodbye | type: 0}
>   Struct2: {value: -531387940 | type: 1}

What would be the proper way to print this? I've also put it here: https://onlinegdb.com/S17HrvNPB

Comment: `*((int *) val3.value)`  should do the job because `value` contains an address. I am on my phone, srry if i got something wrong.

Comment: Consider using a union.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  Since the parameters `argc` and `argv[]` are not used, The compiler will output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Struct2: {value: %d | type: %d}\n", (int) val3.value, val3.type);`  results in the compiler outputting the message: *untitled.c:26:49: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]*  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Struct2: {value: %d | type: %d}\n", *((int *) val3.value), val3.type);
```

This should do the job.

A `void *` holds an address of any type. You have stored `&number` in it. Now if you want to print it, first of all you need to access that address. You can't access an address that is stored in `void *` without typecasting. This is because, compiler won't understand how many bytes at that address need to be accessed. `void *` just points to the starting of that address.

So to tell the compiler that we need to access `sizeof(int)` bytes, we first typecast it into `(int *)` and then to get the value at that address, we do `*((int *) val3.value)`.

Here consider reading more about `void *`:
[What does void* mean and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it/11629682)