# Function that takes a reference to another function with no arguments

Tags: c

I am wondering how the `RecieveInit` function takes the `CMD_GetChar` function as an argument with no parameters. From what I understand, the `ReceiveInit` takes an `rxChar` argument which is a pointer to a `uint8_t`. It is then cast as a pointer to a `void` object (`*RxCb`), where `CMD_GetChar` takes a pointer to a `uint8_t`.

```c
void CMD_Init(void)
{
  ReceiveInit( CMD_GetChar );
}

void ReceiveInit(  void (*RxCb)(uint8_t *rxChar) )
{
}

static void CMD_GetChar( uint8_t* rxChar)
{
}
```

How is `CMD_GetChar` being computed within `ReceiveInit` when it doesn't even have an argument to parse?

Comment: The argument isn't needed until the function is actually called.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  `ReceiveInit` takes a pointer to function as its sole argument.  That function takes a pointer to a `uint_8_t` as its argument, and returns `void`.  So `CMD_GetChar` qualifies, and a pointer to it can be passed to `ReceiveInit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is void \*function() a pointer to function or a function returning a void\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500806/is-void-function-a-pointer-to-function-or-a-function-returning-a-void)